# Getting value of php variable in html page

Tags: php, html

I would like to access my php variables obtained via PHP script on HTML page

this is my php script:

```
<?php
    $url="http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=funny+cat&offset=100&limit=1&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC";

    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $file = json_decode($json);
    $images = $file->data[0]->images;

    $entityUrl =  $file->data[0]->images->original->mp4;
    $entityId =  $file->data[0]->id;
?>
```

and this is my html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php include "start.php" ?>
 <video width="320" height="240" autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="<? echo $entityUrl ?> " type="video/mp4" />
</video> 
</body>
</html>
```

but in this configuration my code does not work. Any ideas? Name of php file = "start.php" , html file "starting_page.html", both in the same directory.

Comment: *'and this is my html page"* - being what extension? `.html`? `.php`? other?

Comment: how does the php relate to the html? variables create in one php script exist ONLY in that script. they do not magically become permanent/global variables for all scripts.

Comment: instruct your server to treat `.html` files as PHP. Otherwise, you'd need to use a `.php` extension while making sure short tag's enabled.

Comment: whether I run this in php or html file , for me that doesnt matter

Comment: besides .html not being able to include a PHP file without some config teaks, this wont work`<? echo $entityUrl ?>`  You need to use the full PHP tag `<?php`  OR the short tag syntax `<?=$entityUrl ?>`

Comment: Please check this link:-http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php

Comment: then I for one, am obviously not grasping the question.

Comment: all I want to do is acces variable obtained in php script inside of html <video> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a .htaccess file at the your folder (or root folder of your website) and add this line:

- if you are using Apache2 @ Ubuntu/Debian:

  `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm`
- if your are running PHP as CGI:

  `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm`

And also replace in your html file:

```
<? echo $entityUrl ?>
```

with:

```
<?= $entityUrl ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $entityUrl; ?>
```

Comment: tbh I have no idea, I'm using XAMPP and running Apache , so I suppose AddType counts for me,

Comment: the first option should work for you: `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm`

Comment: You can also edit `c:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf` file by adding `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm` and restart your apache2 service. But it will be global solution. If you want apply that for specified directory only - use .htaccess solution above.

Comment: @filemonczyk If it is not important for you - just change .html file extension to .php

Answer (score 2):

Make it easier on yourself and just make one .php file like so:

```
<?php
  $url="http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=funny+cat&offset=100&limit=1&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC";

  $json = file_get_contents($url);
  $file = json_decode($json);
  $images = $file->data[0]->images;

  $entityUrl =  $file->data[0]->images->original->mp4;
  $entityId =  $file->data[0]->id;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="ISO-8859-1"/>
   <title>Insert title here</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <video width="320" height="240" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="<?php echo ''.$entityUrl.''; ?> " type="video/mp4" />
   </video> 
  </body>
 </html>
```

Then you dont have to mess around with htaccess/rewrites

Comment: Wasnt sure as he didnt say

Comment: Im in php since 2h, and tought that's bad practice

Comment: Anytime you are using php it has to be in a .php file. You can include a .html file into a php file but not the other way around

Comment: No, that is not bad practice. Just make two .php files: one witch extracting url src of video, and second one for view (just your html code in file with .php extension instead .html)

Comment: There is other way around: .htaccess trick or general apache (web server) configuration

Comment: Yeah but why go through that trouble when you can just save it as a .php file and get the same result

Comment: OK, I changed the file to .php